# Rayleigh scattering question

Tags: optics

Usually from books, Rayleigh scattering only refers to the light scattering by neutral atoms or molecules. For example if I want to measure temperature or number density in combustion using Rayleigh scattering, and a lot of combustion intermediate species are not really neutral, do I have to take care of the scattering signal from ions? Same question to plasma measurement because of ionization. Thanks.

Comment: We don't have a large number of experimental physicists on the site, so the probability that someone here has done this experiment is small. Have you tried the [obvious Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rayleigh+scattering+flame)? Some of the hits seem highly relevant to your experiment.